# Converting access IIF to tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

```
select 
    Project,
    Max([WeekStart] + (Right(IIf([monday] > 0, 0) AND IIf([tuesday] > 0, 1) 
        AND IIf([wednesday] > 0, 2) AND IIf([thursday] > 0, 3) 
        AND IIf([friday] > 0, 4) AND IIf([saturday] > 0, 5) 
        AND IIf([sunday] > 0, 6), 1))) AS LastProjectResourceDate
from 
    ProjectTable t
group by 
    t.Project
```

The bit in the `MAX()` function is from MS Access and I need to convert it to t-sql . Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, and perhaps some example results?  The use of the Right function and the ANDs make it difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Note that SQL Server 2012 and later already has an [`IIF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep applying your WHEN condition until the end of all possible tests.  Whichever qualifier is true first wins.

```
Max( [WeekStart] 
  + CASE when [monday] > 0 then 0
         when [tuesday] > 0 then 1
         when [wednesday] > 0 then 2
         when [thursday] > 0 then 3
         when [friday] > 0 then 4
         when [saturday] > 0 then 5
         when [sunday] > 0 then 6
         else 0 end  LastProjectResourceDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the case statement. Instead of `IIF(A, B, C)` use `case when A then B else C end`. In your case you aren't specifying `C`. `IIF` will substitute `0`, so you need to put that.

So instead of

```
IIf([tuesday]>0,1)
```

Use

```
case when [tuesday] > 0 then 1 else 0 end
```

Also instead of using `And` for bitwise and, use `&`.

Finally, I have no idea what the code is intended to do but ***it looks like it doesn't do it***.